# Is there a way in a class function to return an instance of the class itself?

Tags: python, class, return, instance

I have a class in python with a function and I need that function to explicitly return an instance of that class. I tried this

```
class a(type):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def foo() -> a:
        return a(self.n + 1)
```

but I get an error "a is not defined". What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: There are several things wrong here - in `foo` there is no `self`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was an example, not the actual code I'm working with. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP used annotation in member function. There is a NameError in the annotation also. To fix that. Try following:

Reference:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id34

> Annotating instance and class methods
>
> In most cases the first argument of class and instance methods does
>   not need to be annotated, and it is assumed to have the type of the
>   containing class for instance methods, and a type object type
>   corresponding to the containing class object for class methods. In
>   addition, the first argument in an instance method can be annotated
>   with a type variable. In this case the return type may use the same
>   type variable, thus making that method a generic function.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='a')


class a:
    def __init__(self: T, n: int):
        self.n = n

    def foo(self: T) -> T:
        return a(self.n + 1)


print(a(1).foo().n)
```

Result:

```
2
```

Comment: Good to know! Why do you type hint `self` though? Is there any (reasonable) way to get that wrong?

Comment: how can this code be refactored in order to be DRY? I don't want to type class's name twice.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking works:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def foo(self):
        return A(self.n + 1)


a = A(1)
b = a.foo()

print(a.n, b.n)
```

There are sevaral problems with your original code though.

- The type hint `-> A` does not work because `A` is not defined at that point.
- You need to pass `self` to the `foo` method as well.
- If you subclass `type`, and want to make use of its features, I suggest you also initialize it by calling `super().__init__()` and pass on all necessary arguments. You can do that at any point you prefer, but usually it's done in the `__init__()` method of the subclass.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!